# Signs of obfuscated code

Tags: javascript

How do you find out if a .js source file of a website is obfuscated? Since the source file is visible in the source of the HTML, the code is available, but usually written in a cryptic manner.

So for example, if I were to try viewing the .js file of a website like Soundcloud, it shows all this jumbled up code. Is that the indication of it being obfuscated?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: ... Yes.... If you open it and it is obfuscated, then... it's obfuscated. Am i miss-understanding the question?

Comment: Probbaly an indication of minified code

Comment: @NiklasB. I'm asking how to find out if a source file is obfuscated, or it was literally written just like it appears to us when we view it in our browser.

Comment: That is literally how it is saved on the server. Or, more precisely, how the web server is returning it. I guess it's possible to obfuscate on the fly, but that's very bad from an efficiency point of view.

Comment: @Joseph The developers probably did not write it in the form you see it in the browser. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the code is simply *jumbled up*, it's very likely that it is *minfied*. This involves removing all non-essential white-space from the document, turning:

```
function foo ( arg1, arg2 ) {
    return arg1 * arg2;
}
```

Into something like:

```
function foo(arg1,arg2){return arg1*arg2;}
```

Further, some developers will replace method and variable names as well as part of their minification process:

```
function a(b,c){return b*c;}
```

This further reduces the code. You can still expand this out with most browsers though. The last I checked, every major browser (Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Internet Explorer, and Safari) all support Pretty Code.

[image]

As for how they do it, it's usually part of a build step. Prior to uploading their source to the server, they run a series of operations against it. Typically this involves checking the code for bad patterns, running unit tests, and more. One additional step is minification and concatenation (shrinking, and joining multiple files).

If you would like to do this with your projects, I'd encourage you to look into [Grunt.js](http://gruntjs.com/) or [Gulp.js](http://gulpjs.com/). Both have configurable tasks that will help you manage the size and legibility of your output.

Comment: Does minifying the code bring out any noticeable changes in performance? Or is it just done to make it less accessible to other users.

Comment: It's done to reduce the file size which in turn reduces load times. As you can see from the GIF above, minifying does nothing to make the code less accessible to a programmer that knows how to use the tools available to him.

Comment: @JosephPotts It's almost always about fewer/faster HTTP requests.

Comment: So even if a kilobyte is saved after obfuscating the code, it makes a reasonable difference?

Comment: @JosephPotts That depends on a lot of factors. Why don't you try it with your code to get a good sense of whether it's worth the effort or not?

Comment: @NiklasB. I'll try it on some projects I'm working on. Thanks!

Comment: @JosephPotts Imagine what 1k means to a service like Stack Overflow, which has millions of users. That's millions of kilobytes saved, on every request. Goes a long way.

Comment: @JonathanSampson assuming no caching on the client side...

Comment: @NiklasB. You still have to send it to them in order for it to be cached.